Проверка пароля на надежность
Помогите разработать код проверки надежности пароля через Tkinter. Постоянно выдает ошибку
from tkinter import *.
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Проверка пароля")
root.geometry("400x150")

frame = Frame(
    root,
    padx=10,
    pady=10
)
frame = Frame(master=root, relief=SUNKEN, borderwidth=5) 
frame.pack(expand=True)


password_lbl = Label(
    frame,
    text='Введите интересующий пароль'
)
password_lbl.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10)
password_ent = Entry(
    frame
)
password_ent.grid(row=3, column=2)
password_ent.focus()
    
def check(password): 
    number = '1234567890'
    upper_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    symbols = '!*._'
    acceptable = number + upper_letters + lower_letters + symbols 

    passwd = set(password) 
    if any(char not in acceptable for char in passwd):
        messagebox.showerror('Информация', f'Пароль {password} неверен.')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Информация', f'Пароль {password} верен.')

proverka_Btn = Button(frame, text="Проверить", command=check)  
proverka_Btn.grid(row=5, column=2)

root.mainloop() 


Какую ошибку выдает код? Может быть, в первой строке? И зачем импортировать из tkinter все и еще messagebox?

from tkinter import *. - точка не нужна.
Однако, есть более интересный вопрос: а как Вам удалось до сих пор писать без ошибок? Я взял этот код, выполнил его в стандартном IDLE, об ошибке мне сразу же рассказали.  Я так понимаю, код не Ваш, и отсутствует даже хоть какое-то базовое обучение. Я, например, уже будучи достаточно опытным в смысле синтаксиса, ошибаюсь раз двадцать за день. Первая ошибка должна была появиться у Вас перед глазами в первые же полчаса программирования в среде Питон. :-)))))))))))))))))
Работа с ошибками - первая ступень программирования в любой среде.

Точки в коде нет, не совсем понимаю откуда она тут взялась.

Я ж написал, если убрать точку, код исполняется в среде IDLE. Посмотрите на условие - первая строка. Что ещё не работает?

Не совсем понимаю, что Вы хотите сделать. Единственная ошибка, которую мне вывело TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password' показывает на то, что у Вас в строке proverka_Btn = Button(frame, text="Проверить", command=check) вызов функции без аргументов. Решается с помощью лямбды. Но проблема в самом коде:
Что вы пытаетесь передать тут как аргумент? - def check(password):
Вы получаете пароль из своего Entry с помощью метода .get():
def check(): 
    number = '1234567890'
    upper_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    lower_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    symbols = '!*._'
    acceptable = number + upper_letters + lower_letters + symbols 

    password = password_ent.get()
    if any(char not in acceptable for char in password):
        messagebox.showerror('Информация', f'Пароль {password} неверен.')
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Информация', f'Пароль {password} верен.')

proverka_Btn = Button(frame, text="Проверить", command=check)  
proverka_Btn.grid(row=5, column=2)

И Вы будете получать пароль, который ввел пользователь, без ошибок.
P.s: from tkinter import * так лучше не делать, вместо этого можно писать import tkinter as tk и выводить методы Tkinter через tk(Пример: root = tk.Tk())
